# Azure ARM access token wrong audience

Tags: powershell, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to get information from Azure ARM about a specific resource. Currently I was able to get the access token from oAuth2 using the following article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow, however when I try to use it I get the following error:

> Invoke-RestMethod :
> {"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience","message":"The
> access token has been obtained for wrong audience or resource
> '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. It should exactly match with
> one of the allowed audiences
> 'https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.core.windows.net','https://management.azure.com/','https://management.azure.com'."}}

Below is the code that I am attempting to run:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.String] $ResourceId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.String] $APIVersion
)
function Urls-Authorization
{
    [OutputType([System.Uri])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [System.Guid] $TenantId
    )
    return [System.Uri]::new("https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TenantId)/oauth2/token")
}
function Urls-Management
{
    [OutputType([System.Uri])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    return [System.Uri]::new("https://management.azure.com")
}
function Urls-Resource
{
    [OutputType([System.Uri])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    return [System.Uri]::new((Urls-Management), "$($ResourceId)?api-version=$($APIVersion)")
}
function ConvertFrom-SecureString
{
    [OutputType([System.String])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [SecureString] $SecureString
    )
    return [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($SecureString))
}
function New-AccessToken
{
    [OutputType([System.String])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.Uri] $ResourceUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.Guid] $TenantId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.Guid] $ClientId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [SecureString] $Password,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [System.DateTime] $Expires = ($(Get-Date).AddMinutes(60).ToUniversalTime()),
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [System.DateTime] $NotBefore = ([System.DateTime]::UtcNow)
    )
    #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow
    $AuthorityUrl = Urls-Authorization -TenantId $TenantId
    try
    {
        $RequestBody = [ordered]@{
                                        'grant_type'    = 'client_credentials';
                                        'client_id'     = $ClientId;
                                        'scope   '      = $ResourceUrl;
                                        'client_secret' = "$(ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $Password)";
                                    }
        $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $AuthorityUrl -Method Post -Body $RequestBody -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Log -Type ERROR -Message "Token could not be acquired"
        throw
    }
    return $Response.access_token
}
function Headers
{
    [OutputType([Hashtable])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [System.String] $ContentType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.String] $AccessToken
    )
    $Headers = @{}
    if ($ContentType -ne $null) {$Headers.Add("Content-Type", $ContentType)}
    $Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $($AccessToken)")
    return $Headers
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri (Urls-Resource) -Headers (Headers -ContentType "application/json" -AccessToken (New-AccessToken -ResourceUrl (Urls-Management) -TenantId $env:AZURE_TENANT_ID -ClientId $env:AZURE_CLIENT_ID -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $env:AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET -AsPlainText -Force))) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

As I mentioned before, I get the access token with **New-AccessToken** function. I even attempt the following and I get the same error:

1. Change the ResourceUrl parameter in New-AccessToken from Urls-Management to Urls-Resource
2. Add /.default to Urls-Management address
3. Add change Urls-Management from **https://management.azure.com** to **https://management.azure.com/**

Do you know what can be happening? Any idea about how should I face this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is providing some good insights. I would change `New-AccessToken` to:

```
function New-AccessToken
{
    [OutputType([System.String])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.Uri] $ResourceUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.Guid] $TenantId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.Guid] $ClientId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [SecureString] $Password,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [System.DateTime] $Expires = ($(Get-Date).AddMinutes(60).ToUniversalTime()),
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [System.DateTime] $NotBefore = ([System.DateTime]::UtcNow)
    )
    #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow
    $AuthorityUrl = Urls-Authorization -TenantId $TenantId
    try
    {
        $RequestBody = [ordered]@{
                                        'grant_type'    = 'client_credentials';
                                        'client_id'     = $ClientId;
                                        'scope   '      = $ResourceUrl;
                                        'client_secret' = "$(ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $Password)";
                                        'resource'      = 'https://management.azure.com/';
                                    }
        $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $AuthorityUrl -Method Post -Body $RequestBody -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Log -Type ERROR -Message "Token could not be acquired"
        throw
    }
    return $Response.access_token
}
```

Basically, add `'resource' = 'https://management.azure.com/';` in the `$RequestBody`. I have a couple of Azure Rest calls in this [repository](https://github.com/vivere-dally/azure_rest_groovy/blob/main/src/Main.groovy), but it is in groovy (though this shouldn't be an issue).

Moreover, have you considered using the [Az](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/5.8.0) module? It implements all the rest logic behind the scenes and provides ready to use cmdlets that communicate with the Azure Resources.

Comment: Thanks, it works. We can not use Az module cmdlets as the solution will be cloud hosted and Microsoft does not provide support for Az modules on Azure, only for AzureRM and some of the AzureRm cmdlets does not provide the information that we are looking for